# Moving Pending Queue from Redis to Database - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, redis

I want to upgrade my redis server which might cause the data to be wiped out, which is okay except the pending queues. Some of the queues delayed to be run next year (so I can't wait until all cleared).

I have two options in my mind:

1. Manually pump the pending queues into new redis connection (more than 20+ pending queues)
2. Moving the pending queues to Database 'jobs' table

Which one is better? And also how best to do it? Or any other options there?

Thank you.